# How to map a set of classes from a jar library to a jpa entities to create the database tables

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm adding a library on my pom.xml...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mx.bigdata.cfdi</groupId>
    <artifactId>cfdi-base</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

[bigdata-mx/factura-electronica](https://github.com/bigdata-mx/factura-electronica)

This library let me import a set of classes that I use to create objects inside my project t (to create invoicing information)... the data from this objects should be send to the database...

For now, I have to map each class from the library, to the jpa entity class, with this, I can save data to the database...

The class library is like this...

```
package mx.bigdata.sat.cfdi.v32.schema;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "",
    propOrder = {"emisor", "receptor", "conceptos", "impuestos", "complemento", "addenda"}
)
@XmlRootElement(
    name = "Comprobante"
)
public class Comprobante implements Serializable {
...
}
```

My Entity mapping class look like this...

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "facturacion")
public class Comprobante implements Serializable {
}
```

But, I'm looking for a way to import the classes from the library... and a manner to define it as jpa entities for create the database tables directly from the classes of the library.

This is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [define mappings in xml](https://dzone.com/articles/persisting-entity-classes).

This is suitable in cases when you can't add annotations to entities because you import them from a library or when the entities are created with some code auto-generation tools during build, so your manual changes would always be overwritten.